# Why is PanSource marked as Obsolete?

Tags: c#, cscore

I'm trying to create a simple stereo pan control. Why is PanSource marked as obsolete and why should I use the DmoChannelResampler instead? It seems that it is overly complex to create a simple stereo pan.

Comment: Ask the devs. Otherwise we are just guessing.

Comment: Should I open an issue on github?

Comment: @Guilheme: That's completely up to you. I'd look over the release notes too, there maybe some hint in there.

Comment: PanSource allows you to control the balance of a stereo audio source. It's implementation works but is quite minimalistic. For future it is recommended to use the DmoChannelResampler which provides much more features like mapping channels, controling the volume of each channel individually and of course changing the sample rate,...
You still can use the PanSource but it's features are quite limited compared to the DmoChannelResampler.